# IOS first time launch get the link user downloaded the app from

Tags: ios, mobile, dynamic-linking

I need to get the link that the user clicked on to download the App . 
how can I do this ? I couldn't find anything (except of firebase which enforces me to implement "Sign in with google" )

Comment: Firebase does this : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/
you can create a link and retrieve it on launch

Comment: The Appsflyer service can generate a link that is detectable in run time, if you add their SDK to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a deferred deep linking service that passes web context in after download. The best option [Branch's iOS SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/). They have the most reliable deferred deep linking.

Comment: I prefer not use SDKs , can you direct me to something that explains how to do this ?

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to build the infrastructure on your own. You can try and build out fingerprinting, but iOS cookie sharing is discontinued. You pretty much HAVE to use an SDK for this. Is there a reason you don't want to?